# Type safe parameter in method

Tags: java, android, annotations, type-safety

I'm using a library which provides custom `View`s. I want to create a method that accepts only custom `View`s from this library.

E.g. I have a `PieChart` and a `TableChart`. `TableChart` extends `LinearLayout` but `PieChart` extends some internal `abstract` chart which extends `View`. So, I don't have any abstract class or interface that can describe both these objects.

Currently my method looks like this:

```
void draw(View chart, ChartData data) {
    switch (data.getType()) {
        case PIE_CHART:
            PieChart<Numeric> pieChart = (PieChart<Numeric>) chart;
            // ...
            break;
        case TABLE_CHART:
            TableChart tableChart = (TableChart) chart;
            // ...
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

So, I can actually pass any `View` as a `chart` parameter, which doesn't look good. I was thinking of creating some annotation such as `@IntDef` in android but for class objects (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html). I looked at the source code and tried to create something similar but it didn't work. I'm still able to pass any `View` as a parameter:

```
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
  @Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
  @interface ClassDef {
    Class<? extends View>[] value() default {};
  }

  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
  @ClassDef({PieChart.class, TableChart.class})
  @interface ChartView {}

  void draw(@ChartView View chart, ChartData data) // doesn't work
```

I'm not really familiar with java annotations though. Does anybody know if this is possible to create such annotation that will allow to pass only specific classes as a parameter?
Maybe there is some other approach to achieve type-safety? I can't change the source code of classes inside library.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I provided `PieChart` and `TableChart` as examples. In my app I have about 10 types of charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after researching all possible solutions, I decided to use composition. I created my own wrappers around those charts and tables and then implemented my own `interface`:

```
interface AppChart {
    void setupChart();
    void bindChart(ChartData data);
}

class AppPieChart<T> implements AppChart {
    private PieChart<T> chart;

    public AppPieChart(PieChart<T> chart) {
        this.chart = chart;
    }

    @Override
    public void setupChart() {
        //...
    }

    // ...
}

class AppTableChart implements AppChart {
    private TableChart chart;

    public AppTableChart(TableChart chart) {
        this.chart = chart;
    }

    @Override
    public void setupChart() {
        //...
    }

    // ...
}
```

So, my `draw` method is now type-safe:

```
void draw(AppChart chart, ChartData data) {
    switch (data.getType()) {
        case PIE_CHART:
            AppPieChart<Numeric> pieChart = (AppPieChart<Numeric>) chart;
            // ...
            break;
        case TABLE_CHART:
            AppTableChart tableChart = (AppTableChart) chart;
            // ...
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can define two public methods, one that takes a PieChart and one that takes a TableChart.  This will give you type safety.  If there is shared logic then you can call a private or protected method from your public methods.  The annotation approach won't work.

Comment: ok, thank you. Your approach is fine if I had only these two charts, but unfortunately I have about 10 types which will give me 10 methods.. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Writing annotations is a good choice, because it does not require you to change your source code, it does not impose any run-time overhead, and it can give you a compile-time guarantee that clients use the library correctly.

Just writing annotations is not enough.  When compiling, you also need to supply an annotation processor that issues a compilation error if you misuse the annotations.  So, the code that you showed is a good start, but it is missing the annotation processor.

You can write your own annotation processor, or you can use an existing one.  One that you might find useful is the [Checker Framework](http://checkerframework.org/).  It seems well-suited to your use case:  you could use the [Subtyping Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#subtyping-checker) and compile your code with a command such as

```
javac -processor org.checkerframework.common.subtyping.SubtypingChecker \
-Aquals=ChartView MyFile.java
```

Comment: This is really interesting info, I didn't know about that. I will take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is :

```
void draw(View chart, ChartData data) throws Exception {
    if(!(chart instanceof TableChart || chart instanceof PieChart)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    switch (data.getType()) {
        case PIE_CHART:
            PieChart<Numeric> pieChart = (PieChart<Numeric>) chart;
            // ...
            break;
        case TABLE_CHART:
            TableChart tableChart = (TableChart) chart;
            // ...
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is possible, but slow. I call this method frequently because I draw charts in `RecyclerView` items. `instanceof` is a heavy operation which I will have to perform for each chart type. And it doesn't help me with type-safety: I'm still able to pass any `View` to the method and I still need to `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.